# basic multiple answers quiz system checkbox ambiguity

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to build a basic quiz system and everything seems ok.

The following code shows how a users choose the correct answer and the `getresult.php` shows the result. In my database, there is a question, opt1, opt2, opt3 opt4 and answer column.

```
<form method="POST" action="getresult.php">
   <label>Enter Your Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text"  name="name" required><br><br>
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM quiz");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();

        while($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<form method='POST' action='getresult.php'>";
    echo $myrow['id'];
    echo ".";   
    echo $myrow['question'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mycheck[]' value=".$myrow['opt1'].">";
        echo $myrow['opt1'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mycheck[]' value=".$myrow['opt2'].">";
    echo $myrow['opt2'];
        echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mycheck[]' value=".$myrow['opt3'].">";
    echo $myrow['opt3'];
        echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mycheck[]' value=".$myrow['opt4'].">";
    echo $myrow['opt4'];
        echo "<br><br>";

    }
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Results" class="btn btn-primary">
```

> getresult.php

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM quiz");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
$myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();

$totalCheckboxChecked = sizeof($_POST['mycheck']);

$submit=isset($_POST['submit']);

$count=0;

if($submit)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$totalCheckboxChecked;$i++)
   {

               if($mycheck[$i]==$myrow['answer'])
        {   
            $count=$count+1;
        }

   }
    echo "Hello ";
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "You scored ";
    echo $count;

}
```

Now the **problem** is with the checkbox, I can check all the values from all the questions. And when I use radio button I can check only one value from all questions. How can I check only one value from one question.

Comment: are there supposed to be multiple allowable answers in the checkboxes? if not - then use radio buttons, which only allow A or B or C or D... what the checkboxes will do it to say A and B are acceptable answers. fine but if only one answer per question is expected - radio buttons are better

Comment: if answer contain only one value then radio button is better option if your answer contain two values then use checkbox with multiple select

Comment: @arun kumaresh the problem with the radio button is i am allowed to choose only one option from whole lot of quolestions because of that while loop.

Comment: are you want to select multiple answer from the questions

Comment: you need to rethink this - you can easily modify your code to allow the available answers to be used with radio buttons - using checkboxes to do the job of radiobuttons is like using a scalpel as a butter knife... sure they are both knives but its just wrong. I too am creating a multiple choice quiz at hte moment, and pulling both questions and answers from the database with php and I have radio buttons for each question  /answe cycle!

Comment: @gavgrif the problem with radio button is i am allowed to choose only one question from whole lot of questions because of that while loop.

Comment: bollocks - you do a loop within a loop - the first loop gets the question id and then you use that question id to get the answers and display them with radio buttons and so the answers relate to the question id of the parent loop!

Comment: @gavgrif ok.that should be it

Comment: i would also suggest splitting out the answers to a database table of their own with the question id being a foreign key. rather than what i think you have done with the answers being in the same table as the questions. Actually if you are planning on having more than one quiz, it should be a quiz table (with quiz id being hte primary key), a questions table with question_id being primary and the quiz_id being foreign, and an answer table with answer_id being primary and the question_id being foreign.

Comment: I also have a responses table as well into which i insert the answers provided by the student to allow the comparison against the correct answer and to allow a review of the quiz to demonstrate which questions were answered correctly and what the missed answers were  and a results table to store the results against the students id

Comment: @gavgrif that would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: @gavgrif i am bit confused with loop within a loop. i gave a separate name to the answers of each question using the id of that question using the loop but failed.

Comment: try creating a db connection with a query that yields a question id, then interrupt that query with a second one that uses that question id as a parameter that yields all answers with that question id - complete that loop and then complete the initial loop. a query within a query!

Comment: @gavgrif the problem is with getresult.php while comparing with the answer, how do i add loop there.   Please answer

Comment: nope you have to research stuff to learn it - this is a forum for assistance and I have assisted you with the direction in which you need to look - more than that - I  will be writing your code and you will not be learning how to do it for the future - it is a simple concept - step back from the issue and try to write a query within a query yourself - you will learn more than if i do it for you. I am a teacher and firmly believe t=in the power of self learning!

Comment: @gavgrif  ok.  I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're not using radio buttons if you plan to allow only one selection, but you can set a limit to have the same thing with checkboxes with some JavaScript (or jQuery).

Here is an example: [see fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/803/)

```
var limit = 1;

$('input').on('change', function(event) { // this could've been a 'click' event too.

   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;

       /* OR you can do like:
           if($("input[name='mycheck']:checked").length > limit) { //... }
       */

   }

});
```

Comment: I am not using radio buttons because it allows to choose only one option from whole lot of questions  because of that while loop.

Comment: Something is not really clear... Do you want users to pick only one single in the group, disregarding how it is displayed (radio or checkboxes)? If your answer is yes, then you don't need to redo what a radio button does by default using checkboxes. If you still want to do it using the answers you could achieve that but I think that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: i found my problem with the loop that  allows to select only one particular answer from all the questions. that is using radio button.

Answer (score 0):

if the question contain only one answer better use radio buttons to select the option

or 
else

use this jquery to select single value from checkbox

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: what is the value of having checkboxes if the ones not selected are de-checked. If that is the desired effect then radio buttons would be better, and if there are multiple options to be selected then the checkboxes are approppriate but need to allow multiple selections. But to simply de-check the non selected checkboxes makes them pseudo radio buttons and then not chckboxes at all. or am i missing something?

Comment: yes radio button is a better option but he is using checkboxes

Comment: -then the answer should be to stop using checkboxes and to use radiobuttons - unless the questions specifically support multiple correct answers